# What's the rule for the Name-Version-Release of RPM?

Tags: rpm

Imagine a RPM named `abc-123-1.x86.rpm`, and I found a bug in it.

But I don't know how to name the **new** package.

Maybe `abc-123-2.x86.rpm`? But what if there is a `xyz.rpm` depends on `abc-123-1`?

Maybe `abc-123-1.x86.1.rpm`, ...

So my question is **what's the rule for the Name-Version-Release of RPM?**

Answer (score 8):

The question is where is the bug and who fixed it.

The parts of an rpm package/file name are the `name`, the `version`, the `release` and the `architecture` (there's also an `epoch` but that's only used in special circumstances).

If the bug that was fixed was in the software itself then a new release of the software was likely made and it will have a new version number so you package that appropriately (assuming you are packaging new versions of the software for your distribution).

If the bug was in the packaging (or you aren't packaging new versions and you are back-porting the patch) then the software version isn't changing and you can't change that so you change the release instead.

Most packages shouldn't depend on a specific release of another package. (They might have minimum supported versions because they depend on a packaging change or back-ported patch but that's a requirement like `abc < 123-1` and isn't affected by this release bump.)

The Fedora (and so RedHat and CentOS) policies about this is at [Package Versioning](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Package_Versioning). Much more packaging related information is available from in that wiki also.

Comment: +1 this is exactly right. Just wanted to add: "packaging" means .spec file, and it resets to 1 at each version increment. I think distro packagers only increment the release if they apply a (possibly distro-specific) patch on top of a release also.

Comment: It also seems common to overload the 'release' field to indicate the OS (distro) version. E.g. I've seen `.el6` suffix indicating Enterprise Linux.