# How to (forcefully) install a specific package version on Centos

Tags: continuous-integration, centos7, yum, continuous-deployment

In a ci/cd environment, i want to be able to update or downgrade a package to a specific version. To do this with yum, one needs to know the already installed version of a packge, eg one can use `yum install` to install a new package or update to a newer version. `yum downgrade` can be used to replace it with an earlier version.

Is there a way to use one command to install a specific version of a package?

Background: We continuously add new package versions to our yum channel on artifactory, so our yum channel doesn't really reflect a `stable` state. One should be able to install *or downgrade* a specific package with one `yum install <package_name>-<package_version>`

Comment: Maybe i'm overseeing somthing. In a nutshell: package managers (like yum) are use to keep an system up to date, so to install the latest availalbe packages for the system. There are ways to keep some packages on a distinct level (pinning, cherry-picking, etc), but in general it is a good choice to go with the latest available packages. But this may not make sense in a cicd way of deploying. (Is this a fair statement? -- I'm not really sure if this should be package managers use case, we could go for local installation of those packages, and in general one would start with a fresh vm anyways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE#2** (please see below for older answers)

Now going with the following approach:

1. check the already installed version
2. if the specified version is already installed, do nothing
3. if a newer version is installed, do a `yum downgrade`
4. else, do a `yum install` (which also updates)

install-utils.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

EXIT_FAILURE=1

function get_installed_version() {

    pkg_name=$("rpm -q --queryformat \
                          '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}' ${pkg_name}" | tail -1)
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && pkg_name=""
    echo ${pkg_name}
}

function is_version_newer() {
    [[ $1 != $(echo -e "$1\n$2" | sort -V | head -1) ]]
}

function install_package(){
    local pkg_name="$1"
    local pkg_ver_rel="$2"
    local pkg_full_name="${pkg_name}-${pkg_ver_rel}"

    echo "Package to install: $pkg_full_name"
    installed_pkg="$(get_installed_version $pkg_name)"
    echo "Package version installed: $installed_pkg"

    if [[ "$installed_pkg" == "$pkg_full_name" ]]; then
        echo "Requested package version '$pkg_full_name' is " \
             "already installed. Nothing to do."
    elif is_version_newer "$installed_pkg" "$pkg_full_name"; then
        echo "Downgrading to $pkg_full_name ..."
        yum -y downgrade $pkg_full_name \
        && echo "Successfully downgraded to $pkg_full_name" \
        || { echo "Failed to downgrade to $pkg_full_name"; exit $EXIT_FAILURE; }
    else
        echo "Installing $pkg_full_name ..."
        yum -y install $pkg_full_name \
        && echo "Successfully installed package $pkg_full_name" \
        || { echo "Failed to install $pkg_full_name"; exit $EXIT_FAILURE; }
    fi
}
```

**OLDER UPDATE**: The (below answer) is not a good approach. Reason: Often, the version to be installed is not fully specified. So instead of giving '`version`-`release`-`architecture`-`epoch`' (where `architecture` and `epoch` may be omitted) there is only the `version` specified, meaning: The latest available package for `version` shall be used. (eg. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184946/6104519) to "What's the rule for the Name-Version-Release of RPM?"). The approach given here will lead to an implicit downgrade to the last but one available version.

For example, one wants to install version: '0.11.1', which is already installed with version: 0.11.1-1. And available upstream is '0.11.1-SNAPSHOT20171030093532' and '0.11.1-2'. The install will update to the newest '0.11.1-2', but that would not match with the `pkg_full_name`, so a `yum downgrade` is performed, which let's the package manager select the snapshot version to be installed.

**INITIAL ANSWER**

For now, my best guess is to use some combination of `yum install`, '(check installed version)' and `yum downgrade` if it is not the specified version.

Eg:

```
pkg_name="somepackage"
pkg_full_name="somepackage-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT20171027143208"
echo "Installing $pkg_full_name ..."
yum -y install $pkg_full_name || \
{ echo "Failed to install $pkg_full_name"; exit 1; }
installed_package=$(rpm -q --queryformat '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}' ${pkg_name})
if [ "${installed_package}" != "${pkg_full_name}" ]; then
    sudo yum -y downgrade $pkg_full_name || \
    { echo "Failed to downgrade to $pkg_full_name"; exit 1; }
fi
echo "Successfully installed package $pkg_full_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

> One should be able to install a specific package with one `yum install
>   <package_name>-<package_version>`

Indeed. Did you try that? Because that is the exact command you would use to install a specific package with `yum`.

Comment: If there is a newer version installed, yum does not automatically downgrade.   One could do that with: `yum remove <package> && yum install <package_name>-<package_version>`. My question is about doing this with just one command.

Comment: I missed the part about having a newer version already installed. Removing that first is the only method I know of.

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach `yum` supports `downgrade` (via a plug-in) - you can also do it outside of `yum` with the base `rpm` commands if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @user3788685. For using downgrade one needs to know the state the system is in. There is no let's-install-this-exact-version-everytime. Please see my answer on what i came up.